# Cassandra Python driver protocol version and connection limits don't match

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, datastax-python-driver

I am using Datastax python driver version:3.23

Cassandra version: DSE version 5.1.16

### The output from cqlsh gives the following:

`[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.3.5116 | DSE 5.1.16 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Nativeprotocol v4]`

```
cluster = Cluster(['X.X.X.X'],port=9042,auth_provider=provider,protocol_version=4)
max_requests = cluster.get_max_requests_per_connection(0)
max_connections = cluster.get_max_connections_per_host(0)
print(max_connections)
print(max_requests)
```

### Output:-

8
100

Based on the DataStax documentation `max_request_per_host in v4` should be 32,786.

Not sure where is the problem.

[Found similar issue for java drive.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024198/cassandra-java-driver-protocol-version-and-connection-limits-dont-match/62294809#62294809)

Answer (score 2):

32k of requests per connection is the theoretical maximum - it's not the actual number.  Each driver has some constant as max number of the requests per connection. For example, Java driver allows 1024 request per connection, C# - 2048, etc.

You can increase this value by using `cluster.set_max_requests_per_connection` for Python driver, or corresponding functions in other drivers.  But I don't recommend heavily increase of it - if you have too many in-flight requests, this is a sign that your cluster can't cope with the load, and by increasing the setting you're just hiding the real problem.

Comment: I tried to set max_requests using cluster,set_max_requests_per_connection(0,100). It throws an error- has an effect when using protocol_version 1 or 2. I have gone through the source code of python driver, observed set parameters is not supported in NTP version > 2. However, I am able to manually pass lower version using cluster =Cluster(['x.x.x.x'],protocol_version=2). Is there any specific reason for deprecating this feature in python driver. Does this applicable to java driver too.